# Docker AWS access container from Ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, host

Hey I am trying to access my docker container with my aws public IP I don't know how to achieve this. Right now I have a ec2 container ubuntu 16.04 
where I am using a docker image of ubuntu. Where I have installed apache server inside docker image I want to access that using public aws ip.

For that I have tried  docker run -d -p 80:80 kyo here kyo is my image name I can do this but what else I need to do in order to host this container with aws. I know i is just a networking thing I don;t know how to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

What is it when your are getting while accessing port 80 over browser? Is it resolving and says some error?
If not check your aws security group polices, you may need to whitelist port 80.

Login to container and see apache is up and running. You could check for open ports inside the container you are running,

```
netstat -plnt
```

If above all are cleared, there is no clear idea why you can't access it outside. You could then check for apache logs, if something wrong with your configuration.

I'm not sure, if it needs to have **EXPOSE** parameter in you Dockerfile, if you have build your own container.

Go through this, 
[A Brief Primer on Docker Networking Rules: EXPOSE](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/docker-networking-rules/)

**Edited answer :**

You can have a workaround by having **ENTRYPOINT** s.

Have this in your Dockerfile and build an image from it.

```
CMD [“apachectl”, “-D”, “FOREGROUND”]
```

or

```
CMD [“-D”, “FOREGROUND”]
ENTRYPOINT [“apachectl”]
```

Comment: I have a ubuntu 16.04 and I am using docker image ubuntu and I have installed apache in docker and port 80 is open. I don't know what else I need to do.

Comment: I haven't installed apachee on aws ubuntu

Comment: Make sure aws security group is open for Apache.
Login into container and check for apache service status and open ports.

Docker exec -it <container-id> bash

Comment: it is working when I am using docker run -d -p 80:80 kyo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND is there any easy way to do this